# Contact image missing

Tags: contacts

In civiCRM 5.14.1. and Joomla 3.9.10, the contact image is quickly displayed on the contact summary page, and then disappears again.

[In this video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7dhasn9l37w0o6x/WhereMyImage.MP4?dl=0)  you can see it appears at the 15 second mark and then quickly disappears. I've cleared all my civi cache files, so that isn't the problem.

Any idea what's up?

Comment: At second 00:16 you can see the tabs javascript/css kicks in and obscures the top portion of the contact form. Not just the image but the contact name and the other stuff in that area. I'm not familiar enough with joomla to tell if this is specific to joomla or possibly just a theme conflict. Are you able to temporarily switch themes and see if that helps?

Comment: In Joomla, I'm using the isis template, which I'll guess 100% of Joomla users, since the alternative (hathor)  is absolutely horrifyingly messy! I did switch to test this theory, but alas, the contact photo still doesn't appear.

Comment: Ha ha ok. Also ignore my comment about the contact name etc - I was seeing something that wasn't there. If you right-click where the image should be and choose Inspect you'll see some html and css. You can also while in there press CTRL-F and search for `crm-contact-thumbnail`. That should help track down where it is hiding.